# How to detect when an image in a canvas is clicked or at least get its location?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this canvas mousedown event:

```
$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e) {
    var coords = canvas.getMousePos(e); // user helper function

    if (coords.x >= 0 && coords.x <= 16 && coords.y >= 32 && coords.y <= 48) {
        tool = "fill";
    } else if (coords.x >= 16 && coords.x <= 32 && coords.y >= 32 && coords.y <= 48) {
        tool = "circle";
    }
});
```

I am also drawing images on this canvas like so in my document ready function:

```
var imgCircle = new Image();
imgCircle.src = "circle.png";

imgCircle.onload = function() {
    toolboxContext.drawImage(imgCircle, 16, 32);
}
```

I don't like using hardcoded values like that in my if statements. I was wondering if there was a way to either get the local coordinates of the images in the canvas or actually register events for the clicking of said images. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you looked into using canvas library like [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't register directly events on your objects but it's easy to register events on the canvas as in

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
```

(you're maybe more interested in "mouseup")

And then you can get the coordinates in the canvas with

```
e.pageX-$(canvas).offset().left
```

and

```
e.pageY-$(canvas).offset().top
```

(here using jQuery for easy cross-platform positionning of the canvas but you can use standard javascript)

After that, you just have to compare with the positions of your images that you must keep somewhere. I personnally use for that effect a Rect class :

```
function Rect(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}
Rect.prototype.contains = function(x, y) {
    return x>=this.x && x<=this.x+this.w && y>=this.y && y<=this.y+this.h;
};
```

Comment: OK. I think I didn't initially understood what your problem is. Why not simply store the pos and sizes of your images in a javascript array somewhere ? That's the simplest part of the whole problem.

Comment: If you confirm this answer is useless, I'll remove it.

Comment: I mean, you're just telling me how to handle the mousedown event and get the local coordinates of the click, which I am already doing in my original post. I'd like to know how to either get the local coordinates of the images or register events on the images themselves.

Comment: You can't : you have to store those coordinates. The Canvas doesn't store it, it isn't a vector object renderer.

Comment: @RyanPeschel - "I'd like to know how to either get the local coordinates of the images...." Don't you *tell* the canvas where to draw the images? If so, you should already know the local coordinates of your images. Just store the coordinates that you hand to the canvas drawing code and reference those in your click code. Or am I missing something as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting this to work like the DOM API. Canvas context objects are just a bundle of methods for painting stuff on a grid of pixels. The grid of pixels is the only real state information that's saved. There's no square or rectangle object holding coords for you. Just methods for splatting rectangles and circles on the map. Maintaining and responding to changes in that info is either DIY or you'll want to look into a library that does it for you.

You CAN however write and listen for new events on generic objects on the fly with jQuery.

```
var someObj = {};
//bind - unfortunate choice for the generic listening method
$(someObj).bind('HiSomeObj',function(){ alert('hi, whoever triggered this event on me'); });
$(someObj).trigger('HiSomeObj'); //'hi, whoever triggered this event on me'

//note how in the following trigger below how I add properties to the event object
```

Here's a crude DIY approach taking advantage of that.

```
//your constructor object - assumes 16px diameter (mostly reusing your code)
function imgCircleObjConstructor16px(xArg, yArg){

    var imgCircle = new Image(),

     //following 2 are var defs and public for convenience

    diameter = this.diameter = 16, //hard-coded for now
    coords = this.coords = [xArg,yArg],
    that = this; //locks down reference to instance for use in JQ

    imgCircle.src = "circle.png";

    this.draw = function(x,y){
        //some function that clears canvas or resets context for redraws
        clearCanvasOrContext();

        toolboxContext.drawImage(imgCircle, x, y);
        this.coords = [x,y];
    }

    $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e) {
        var mouseXY = canvas.getMousePos(e);
        if( mouseXY.x >= coords[0]) && mouseXY.x <= coords[0]+diameter &&
            mouseXY.y >= coords[1] && mouseXY.y <= coords[1] ){

            //trigger custom events with JQ 'trigger' method
            //can't use 'this' because it refers to the jq object for #canvas here
            $(that).trigger('circleBoundingBoxClicked', { someProperty:'optional' } );

            //note: second arg in trigger func serves no purpose
            //just provided as an example of adding properties to event objects

        }
    }
    //might as well tell the circle to draw itself when the object is instantiated:
    this.draw();
}

var myCircle = new imgCircleObjConstructor16px(16,32);

//listen to custom events with 'bind' method
$(myCircle).bind('circleBoundingBoxClicked', function(e){

    var circleObj = e.target; //JQ puts object args from the $ func under target property
    alert('Circle Bounding box at x: '+circleObj.coords[0]+', y:'+circleObj.coords[1]
        +' was clicked. someProperty value: ' + e.someProperty);

//After you fix whatever syntax goofs I didn't test for, this should alert when clicked:
//'Circle Bounding box at x: 15, y:32 was clicked. someProperty value: optional'

} );
```

Now when you use the myCircle.draw method to redraw the circle, the event listener should respond to the new coords.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to get the coordinate x and y of where the user has touched:

```
<canvas id="none"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("none");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.onclick = (e) => {
        let x = e.offsetX;
        let y = e.offsetY;

        console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
    }
</script>
```

with `offset`